# Could not connect to replica set in MongoDB with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect to replica set in MongoDB with the following command:

```
client = MongoClient(
        "PublicIP:27017,PublicIP:27017,PublicIP:27017,PublicIP:27017,PublicIP:27017",
        replicaSet="rs0", readPreference='nearest',
        localThresholdMS=500)

db = client.sampledb


# checks the connection to RS in Mongo
try:
    db.command("serverStatus")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print("\n Connection established to the Replica Set!)
```

I have setup 5 nodes in AWS (1 master, 4 slaves) and the /etc/mongod.conf file in all nodes looks like this:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

    # Where and how to store data.
    storage:
      dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
      journal:
        enabled: true
    #  engine:
    #  mmapv1:
    #  wiredTiger:

    # how the process runs
    processManagement:
      fork: true  # fork and run in background
      pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

    # network interfaces
    net:
      port: 27017
      #bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


    security:
      authorization: "disabled"
    #operationProfiling:

    replication:
      replSetName: rs0
```

When I try to connect from my local machine I get a timed out like this:

> ip:27017: timed out,ip:27017: timed out,ip:27017: timed out,ip:27017:
>   timed out,ip:27017: timed out

Does anyone know why?

Comment: The problem is with your server, most likely its not listening on your given ip/port. Check for open ports and see if your port is in use or not. Make sure your mongod service is running. (Not sure) But try binding to ip 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 - this might not be the problem. Also try connecting with Mongodb Compass / Shell

Comment: My mongod is running. How to check if my server listen on my given port?

Comment: I am assuming you are using linux ```sudo netstat -tulpn``` it should show open ports on your instance

Answer (score 0):

[Starting 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#bind-ip-compatibility) `bindIp` defaults to **localhost only**. So, assuming you are running 3.6 or later your configuration is not accessible from outside, since you commented out `bindIp`.

This post might be helpful to understand some of the nuances: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/enabling-ip-security-for-mongodb-36-on-ubuntu

Obviously, don't forget to make sure AWS Security Group on your instances allows Ingress connection on port 27017.